# How to check string vector for a certain letter or phrase?

Tags: c++

I have a string vector in C++ with this [Apples,Orangesandgrapes], Now i would like too search the vector not for the whole string but the part of the string that says "andgrapes" and would like to change it too, "nograpes". All just an example.

Answer on [Substring search interview question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497310/substring-search-interview-question)
Sorry I couldn't make it clearer.

Comment: So, show us what code you've managed to come up with, so far.

Comment: Try this and an iterator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497310/substring-search-interview-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("Apples");
    v.push_back("Applesandgrapes");
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [] (string& s)
    {
        size_t pos = s.find("andgrapes");
        if(string::npos != pos)
        {
            s.erase(pos);
            s += "nograpes";
        }
    });

        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout));
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: What if "andgrapes" appears in the middle of the string instead of the end?  What if it appears twice in one string?

Answer (score 3):

I would use [boost::replace_all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.replace_hpp) for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>    
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "Apples", "Orangesandgrapes" };    
    for (auto & s : v)    
    {
        boost::replace_all(s, "andgrapes", "nograpes");
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }        
}
```